# MS 7358V and no detected new SSD from Kingston

Tags: linux, ssd

I'm a bit at a loss - I'm currently using an MSi computer. I will then send along the entire system report.

The computer is older and the mainboard is a find from the street. Well - it does what it's supposed to do very well, but only has 4 GB of RAM. That's why it regularly needs the hard drive as a swap file for storage. I now wanted to change this by giving it another 4 GB of RAM.

Unfortunately, none - I couldn't find anything anywhere except on Aliexpress or Amazon. So I got a fancy SSD from a store and already installed it in the computer.

I thought that I could then get the computer to move the swap file to the SSD instead of to the hard drive (PATA)
It even recognizes this great part in the system report, but unfortunately not in the BIOS - not at all - all SATA slots are marked blue and I can't access any of them. Since my current hard drive is still a 160 Gb Pata drive, I haven't given it any thought so far since it doesn't run on SATA.

What have I done myself - nothing, just thinking!!!

1. So - perhaps an update would be necessary - i.e. a bio update of the mainboard. But I've never done it before and to be honest, I'm really happy that it runs without any complaints - I need the thing too.

   Maybe I should say that I assembled it from leftovers and simply didn't want my dual core anymore.
2. I was on the Kingston/flashdrive website - but only read general information there. Maybe the good part needs to be formatted or something - I have no idea - I know my way around hard drives - I just have no idea about the new stuff.
3. Then I thought, maybe the Pata isn't compatible with the Sata etc. - but the system report doesn't show any errors at the moment.

So finally I'm writing to you because I don't know what to do at the moment.

In the case of an update, I just want to be sure that it works and that I can reinstall the old bios if necessary. A new mainboard with DDR 4 costs around 400 euros - I don't have that at the moment.

Thank you very much and best regards to everyone out there - it would of course be great if you could help me - thank you very much for that

```
sun@sonne-G31M-ES2L:~$ lsblk

NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda 8:0 1 447.1G 0 disk
sdb 8:16 0 149.1G 0 disk
├─sdb1 8:17 0 512M 0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2 8:18 0 1K 0 part
└─sdb5 8:21 0 148.6G 0 part /

sdg 8:96 1 14.5G 0 disk
└─sdg1 8:97 1 14.5G 0 part /media/sonne/TOSHIBA

sun@sonne-G31M-ES2L:~$
```

```
System:
Kernel: 5.4.0-169-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0 

Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 

           base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 

Machine:   Type: Desktop System: MEDIONPC product: MS-7358 v: N/A serial: <filter> 

Mobo: MICRO-STAR model: MS-7358 v: Fab D serial: <filter> BIOS: Phoenix v: 6.00 PG   date: 08/06/2007 

CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core2 Quad Q6600 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Core Merom 

rev: B L2 cache: 4096 KiB 

flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19141 

Speed: 2393 MHz min/max: 1600/2400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2393 2: 2393 3: 2057 4: 1905 

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics
vendor: Micro-Star MSI 

driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:29c2 

Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: intel unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 

resolution: 1024x768~60Hz 


OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel G33 v: 1.4 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 

Audio:  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star 

MSI driver:snd_hda_intel v: kernel 

bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:293e 

Device-2: C-Media USB 

Audio Device type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 

bus ID: 6-1:2 chip ID: 0d8c:0012 

Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-169-generic 

Network:   Device-1: Intel 82566DC-2 Gigabit Network

vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: e1000e 

v: 3.2.6-k port: fe00 bus ID: 00:19.0 chip 

ID: 8086:294c IF: enp0s25 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 

Drives:

Local Storage: total: 610.63 GiB used: 110.93 GiB (18.2%) 

ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37480G size: 447.13 
GiB speed: 3.0 Gb/s   serial: <filter> 


ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST3160212A size: 149.05 
GiB speed: <unknown> serial: <filter> 


ID-3: /dev/sdg type: USB vendor: Toshiba model: TransMemory 
size: 14.45 GiB serial: <filter> 


Partition: ID-1: / size: 145.16 GiB used: 109.63 GiB (75.5%) fs: 

ext4 dev: /dev/sdb5 


USB:       Hub: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 6 
rev: 2.0 chip ID: 1d6b:0002 

Device-1: 1-3:2 info: Genesys Logic USB 2.0 33-in-1 Card Reader type: Mass Storage 

driver: usb-storage rev: 2.0 chip ID: 05e3:0710 

Hub: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 6 rev: 2.0 chip ID: 1d6b:0002 

Device-2: 2-2:3 info: Toshiba TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick 

type: Mass Storage driver: usb-storage rev: 2.0 chip ID: 0930:6544 

Hub: 3-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 chip ID: 1d6b:0001 

Hub: 4-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 chip ID: 1d6b:0001 

Hub: 5-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 chip ID: 1d6b:0001 

Hub: 6-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 chip ID: 1d6b:0001 

Device-3: 6-1:2 info: C-Media USB Audio Device type: Audio,HID 
           driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid rev: 1.1 

chip ID: 0d8c:0012 

Hub: 7-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 chip ID: 1d6b:0001 

Device-4: 7-1:2 info: Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc LG Optical Mouse 3D-310 type: Mouse 

driver: hid-generic,usbhid rev: 1.1 chip ID: 1267:0210 

Device-5: 7-2:3 info: Dell Keyboard type: Keyboard driver: hid-generic,usbhid rev: 1.1 

chip ID: 413c:2003 
           Hub: 8-0:1 info: Full speed (or root)

Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 chip ID: 1d6b:0001 

Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 35.0 C mobo: N/A 

           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
```

##### Repos:

No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list

Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list

1: deb https: //mirrors.ptisp.pt/linuxmint ulyssa main upstream import backport

2: deb http: //mirror.tedra.es/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse

3: deb http: //mirror.tedra.es/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

4: deb http: //mirror.tedra.es/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

6: deb http: //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner

Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list

1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //repo.skype.com/deb stable main

Info:
Processes: 236 Uptime: 5h 14m Memory: 3.14 GiB used: 2.24 GiB
(71.1%)

Init: systemd

v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 alt: 9 Client: Unknown
python3.8 client

inxi: 3.0.38

Comment: Was that drive **recommended by the Kingston site**? https://www.kingstonmemoryshop.co.uk/ssd-upgrades

Comment: Additional 4GB won’t prevent the use of a swap file.

Comment: This is my ssd drive: Kingston 480GB A400 SSD 2.5 Inch 7mm, SATA 3.0 (6Gb/s), 500MB/s R, 450MB/s W 
SA400S37/480G
Thank you for your comment - happy new year for you

Comment: Hello to Ramhound - all is better than now. Till I get this Ram type, I thougt - it can be a solution to work with this computer . In the moment there is DDR 2 6400  inside. So I need two other pices of Ram to complete the 8 GB. So you now any possiblity to get them  - hornestly - tell me - Thank you for your comment  - Happy new year for you

Comment: Tell you what exactly?

Comment: Hello - so yet i was on the homepage from MSI , to get the Flash Utility to Update my Bios. But sorry, for MS 7358 there is no Flash Utility. So now I disconnect the SSD and connect the